# Chain guard-case tests with boolean expression

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to 'boolean or' a guard case statement but I am not sure about the correct syntax.

```
enum FooBar {
  case foo
  case bar
  case nope
}

let test = FooBar.foo

guard case test = FooBar.foo else {
  return
}
```

I would like to test against test being `bar`as well, the following syntax is incorrect though:

```
guard case test = FooBar.foo || case test = FooBar.bar else {
  return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `case` keyword for anything. Just check if enum is equal to given case

```
guard test == .foo || test == .bar else {
    return
}
```

Comment: I lost track of what I was going to do with my specific problem. Why the easy way when it's possible to do it the hard way...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead:

```
guard [FooBar.foo, FooBar.bar].contains(test) else {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for using a `guard case`, since you aren't using any complex pattern matching, you're simply testing for equality.

You can simply put all `enum` cases in an Array and call `contains` on that.

```
guard [FooBar.foo, FooBar.bar].contains(test) else {
    return
}
```

Comment: I prefer this over glueing expressions together with ORs (`||`). It's easier to add/remove elements, and scales better when you need to check more things

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains`:

```
guard [FooBar.foo, FooBar.bar].contains(test) else { return }
```